# how do I type the various dashes?

Tags: punctuation

How do I type all the possible dashes:
-,--,---, minus etc. in LaTeX ?
$--$ gives - separated by a space with -.
In math mode or in text mode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that my answer it is useful...you can observe that there are symbol (also the same) in text-mode.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\textemdash, \textendash, $-$, $--$, -, -- , ---
\end{document}
```

[image]

WARNING: One must remember that, in math mode, customary space (in the manner of a binary operator) will be added around the minus sign, if surrounded by math atoms (e.g., `$a-b$` adds extra space around the `-`).

Comment: You might add that the automatic space about the math `-` occurs if there are math atoms on either side of the minus sign.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Hi, Steven, I have not understood your solution. Please, can you edit my answer? Thus I understand.